# Find Kaprekar's Number

Tags: ruby

i am working on the problem of Kaprekar's Number https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/150-kaprekar-s-number. code, i present here, was discussed earlier, but i am interested in another aspect. exercises asks to:

> Find if a given number is a Kaprekar number.

there is a solution (See the Solution) below the exercise, that looks like this:

```
def kaprekar?(k)
  no_of_digits = k.to_s.size
  square = (k ** 2).to_s

  second_half = square[-no_of_digits..-1]
  first_half = square.size.even? ? square[0..no_of_digits-1] : square[0..no_of_digits-2]

  k == first_half.to_i + second_half.to_i
end
```

and is a hint (Need a hint?) below the exercise also:

> Use Fixnum.to_s to convert the number into a string to do digit
>   operations.  Use String.to_i to convert back to integer.

I have a few questions, can anyone explain me:

1) why it is need to convert the number into a string to do digit operations?

2) in the second_half variable i understand that - (minus) sign is the back side of the square, but what does it mean: -1? it must be left side (first_half) n or n-1 digits and not second_half. or is it ending quotation mark, because we converted the number into a string?

3) why is 2 question marks in first_half variable - after 'even' and before 'square'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) why it is need to convert the number into a string to do digit operations?

Because you have to get the second half:

```
second_half = square[-no_of_digits..-1]
```

It's more convenient to deal with string here. This would return last `no_of_digits`, e.g.

```
'1234'[-2..-1] # => '34'
```

`-2..-1` is a [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) of numbers and it's not possible to directly get a range of integer positions.

> in the second_half variable i understand that - (minus) sign is the back side of the square, but what does it mean: -1? it must be left side (first_half) n or n-1 digits and not second_half. or is it ending quotation mark, because we converted the number into a string?

`-1` is the last element. i.e.

```
'1234'[-1] # => 4
```

Similarly, `-n` is n-th from the last element, where `n` is some integer

> 3) why is 2 question marks in first_half variable - after 'even' and before 'square'?

The first question mark is a part of method name. Methods that return boolean values should end with question mark by convention. Notice that `kaprekar?` is no exception.

The second is a part of ternary conditional operator. it looks as follows:

```
boolean_expression ? true_expression : false_expression
```

i.e. `first_half` is either `square[0..no_of_digits-1]` if number of characters in `square` is even or `square[0..no_of_digits-2]` otherwise

Comment: A comment about question #1 for the OP:  Even though you might write a number in your computer program source code as a series of decimal digits, like `2345`, the computer will usually convert that to some kind of binary format (like [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) because those formats are much easier for a computer to work with.  So if you want to work with the decimal digits of the number, you need to convert it back into some form that knows about digits.  One reasonable way to do that is  to convert it to a string.